# Pocketsphinx install does not contain acoustic model definition mdef

Tags: pocketsphinx

I have tried to install pocketsphinx 5 prealpha on windows. But it seems to be stuck in this error below.

**INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none' INFO: cmn.c(143): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0 ERROR: "acmod.c", line 83: Folder 'model/en-us/en-us' does not contain acoustic model definition 'mdef'**

My sphinxbase and pocketsphinx folder is in the same parent folder and I have renamed it as the instruction.

how I compile it

[image]

I have check all the directories and it did contain mdef file without extension.

What should I do?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a proper path to the model folder. You are currently in `bin\Release\x64` folder. In your case the path to the model folder must be `..\..\..\model\en-us\en-us`. If you are not sure what is the relative path, specify an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you run the example code it has MODELDIR and DATADIR variables according to the default but you need to put them according to your file location. Changing the following might sort out the issue

MODELDIR = "/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/"
DATADIR = "/my/Desktop/directory/pocketsphinx-master/test/data/"

This should work ! However I'm not sure. Do u have a better solution?